# Angular 13 ag-grid prependContent

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am working on `Angular ag grid` APIs

I need to add a summary header with data in my exported csv files.
Now can I add summary header with the help of `prependContent`?

Code

```
const params = {
      fileName: 'table-template',
      prependContent: 'Column1,Column2,Column3',
    };
    this.gridApi.exportDataAsCsv(params);
```

Now i can generate the csv like below

[image]

How can i include value as well

[image]

**Edit 1**

ag grid document says

```
With prependContent=CsvCell[][] or appendContent=CsvCell[][], custom content will be inserted containing commas and quotes. These commas and quotes will be visible when opened in Excel because they have been escaped properly.
```

How can we use `CsvCell[][]`.

How can i modify my `prependContent`.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have added below array into `prependContent`,Now its working as expected.

```
      [
        [],
        [{data: { value: 'Column1:', type: 'String'}},
         {data: { value: '100', type: 'String' }},
        ],
        [],
      ],
```

The blank array will make a new empty row

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon the Ag-grid version.
If you are using Ag-grid latest version - v28.2.0, then you have to import the below mentioned modules

```
import { ModuleRegistry } from '@ag-grid-community/core';
import { ClientSideRowModelModule } from '@ag-grid-community/client-side-row-model';
import { CsvExportModule } from '@ag-grid-community/csv-export';
import { MenuModule } from '@ag-grid-enterprise/menu';
```

Also have to register these modules to the ModuleRegistry like this :

```
ModuleRegistry.registerModules([
  ClientSideRowModelModule,
  CsvExportModule,
  MenuModule,
]);
```

Once these modules are registered, then we have to append or prepend the content to ag-grid.
For Example :

```
const getParams = () => ({
  prependContent: getRows()
 });

const getRows = () => [
  { cells: [] },
  {
    cells: [
      {
        data: {
          value: 'Sample Data',
          type: 'String',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  
  { cells: [] },
];

this.gridApi.exportDataAsCsv(getParams());
```